# Replace only 'n' occurences of a substring in a string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I have a input string like -

> abbdabab

How to replace only the **2nd**, *3rd* and *subsequent occurances* of the substring `"ab"` with any random string like `"x"` keeping the original string intact. Example in this case -

> 1st Output - xbdabab 2nd Output - abbdxab 3rd Output - abbdabx and so on...

I have tried using Regex like -

```
int occCount = Regex.Matches("abbdabab", "ab").Count;

if (occCount > 1)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= occCount; i++)
    {
        Regex regReplace = new Regex("ab");
        string modifiedValue = regReplace.Replace("abbdabab", "x", i);
        //decodedMessages.Add(modifiedValue);
    }
 }
```

Here I am able to get the 1st output when the counter `i` value is `1` but not able to get the subsequent results. Is there any *overloaded* `Replace` method which could achieve this ? Or Can anyone help me in pointing where I might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `StringBuilder`:

```
string s = "abbdabab";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, "ab");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
var m = matches[0]; // 0 for first output, 1 for second output, and so on
sb.Remove(m.Index, m.Length);
sb.Insert(m.Index, "x");
var result = sb.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Did not know about the 'Index' and 'Length' properties of 'Regex.Matches' Its so simple and elegant. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `IndexOf` instead of regular expressions:

```
string source = "abbdabab";
string toFind = "ab";
string toSet = "X";

for (int index = source.IndexOf(toFind); 
     index >= 0; 
     index = source.IndexOf(toFind, index + 1)) {
  string result = source.Substring(0, index) + 
                  toSet + 
                  source.Substring(index + toFind.Length);

  Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**Outcome:**

```
Xbdabab
abbdXab
abbdabX
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a dynamically built regex to be used with `regex.Replace` directly:

```
var s = "abbdabab";
var idx = 1; // First = 1, Second = 2
var search = "ab";
var repl = "x";
var pat = new Regex($@"(?s)((?:{search}.*?){{{idx-1}}}.*?){search}"); // ((?:ab.*?){0}.*?)ab
Console.WriteLine(pat.Replace(s, $"${{1}}{repl}", 1));
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/3paX7G)

The pattern will look like `((?:ab.*?){0}.*?)ab` and will match

- `(?s)` - `RegexOptions.Singleline` to make `.` also match newlines
- `((?:ab.*?){0}.*?)` - Group 1 (later, this value will be put back into the result with `${1}` backreference)

  - `(?:ab.*?){0}` - 0 occurrences of `ab` followed with any 0+ chars as few as possible
  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `ab` - the search string/pattern.

The last argument to `pat.Replace` is `1`, so that only the first occurrence could be replaced.

If `search` is a literal text, you need to use `var search = Regex.Escape("a+b");`.

If the `repl` can have `$`, add `repl = repl.Replace("$", "$$");`.